# Mystery Getting Started with Python / pyenv on MacOS Sonoma

Tags: python, zsh, pyenv, macos-sonoma

I learned programming in the MS-DOS environment with Assembly language and C, so please be a little gentle…
I want to use Python (3.12.1 is installed) on MacOS 14.2.1 (Sonoma) where Python 3.9.6 is built in and untouched and Zsh is the shell of choice. The hardware is an Intel based MacBook Pro.
I installed Homebrew and pyenv (mostly because I resist typing 3 after python every time I use it and I have previously had other versions of python installed and there will be more versions in the future).
I had to use various internet articles to get this far…
The problem is I am getting these results:

---

```
<name>@MacBook-Pro ~ % python 
zsh: command not found: python
<name>@MacBook-Pro ~ %
```

---

```
<name>@MacBook-Pro ~ % python3
Python 3.12.1 (v3.12.1:2305ca5144, Dec  7 2023, 17:23:39) [Clang 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.30)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> exit()
<name>@MacBook-Pro ~ %
```

- — - -

  @MacBook-Pro ~ % which python python not found
  @MacBook-Pro ~ %

---

```
<name>@MacBook-Pro ~ % pyenv versions
* system (set by /Users/<name>/.pyenv/version)
<name>@MacBook-Pro ~ %
```

---

```
<name>@MacBook-Pro ~ % pyenv local 3.12.1
pyenv: version `3.12.1' not installed
<name>@MacBook-Pro ~ %
```

---

```
<name>@MacBook-Pro ~ % python -V
zsh: command not found: python
<name>@MacBook-Pro ~ %
```

---

```
My path looks like this:
<name>@MacBook-Pro ~ % echo $path
/Users/<name>/.pyenv/shims /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/bin /usr/local/bin /usr/local/sbin /usr/local/bin /System/Cryptexes/App/usr/bin /usr/bin /bin /usr/sbin /sbin /var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/local/bin /var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/bin /var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/appleinternal/bin
<name>@MacBook-Pro ~ %
```

---

So it appears to me that pyenv isn’t working as expected (by me, at least)
Will someone please help?

Re-read the articles, searched internet for related issues.  Installations seemed to be successful, so I haven't reinstalled anything.  Some instructions /articles used shells other than zsh, so that could be part of the problem or I missed or misinterpreted a step.

Comment: Your path has the pyenv shims directory, which is good -- but if you haven't actually _successfully installed_ any interpreters with pyenv, that directory will be empty; and you haven't as yet shown us that you've done so.

Comment: BTW, personally, I use [Nix](https://nixos.org/) instead of pyenv on MacOS, and strongly recommend it.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy : Do you happen to know, whether `Nix` also can be used to manage different versions of Ruby on the same Mac?

Comment: Maybe I didn't understand you right, but if your only problem is that you don't want to type `python3` in an interactive shell, defining an alias would be sufficient (`alias p=python3`). If you also want to use this "abbreviation" in scripts or from other shells, use a symlink (`mkdir ~/links; ln -s $(which python3) ~/links/p`), and ensure that your `links` directory comes firs in the `PATH`.

Comment: @user1934428, yes, absolutely. There are _some_ limits -- a given release of nixpkgs will only include specific Ruby versions, but you can get older ones from prior nixpkgs releases (the caveat doing that is that old nixpkgs versions are no longer getting security updates); and nothing stops you from mixing packages taken from different sources. So f/e, current nixpkgs includes instructions to build Ruby 2.7, 3.1, 3.2, and 3.3; and its binary caches have binaries for at least some of those if not all (it looks like 3.1.4 is the version marked default currently).

Comment: @user1934428, ...there's also a 3rd-party repo at https://github.com/bobvanderlinden/nixpkgs-ruby that has complete coverage of historical versions.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue while setting up my system

[pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv)

Here you can find for zsh you need to add it to path. Also there are additional associated feature would encourage you to go through the documentation above.

```
echo 'export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"' >> ~/.zshrc
echo '[[ -d $PYENV_ROOT/bin ]] && export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
echo 'eval "$(pyenv init -)"' >> ~/.zshrc
```

The steps are quite clear but one thing it comes down is what processor you are running it on m-series chips or the intel chips.

On additional note you need gcc installed and if installed check for its compatablity

Also I found a medium article very helpful when I was setting it up for the very first time,
[Python: Creating a clean learning environment with pyenv, pyenv-virtualenv & pipX](https://towardsdatascience.com/python-how-to-create-a-clean-learning-environment-with-pyenv-pyenv-virtualenv-pipx-ed17fbd9b790)

Comment: I appreciate the information about zsh additional requirements and the article reference.